# How can I write the clustering results from mclust to file?

Tags: r, printing, mclust

I'm using the mclust library for R ( http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust ) to do some experimental EM-based GMM clustering.  The package is great and seems to generally find very good clusters for my data.

The problem is that I don't really know R at all, and while I have managed to muddle through the clustering process based on the help() contents and the extensive readme, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to write out the actual cluster results to file.  I am using the following absurdly simple script to perform the clustering,

```
myData <- read.csv("data.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)
attach(myData)
myBIC <- mclustBIC(myData)
mySummary <- summary( myBIC, data=myData )
```

at which point I have cluster results and a summary.  The data in data.csv is just a list of multi-dimensional points, one per line.  So each line looks like 'x,y,z' (in the case of 3 dimensions).

If I use 2d points (e.g. just the x and y vals) I can then use the internal plot function to get a very pretty graph that plots the original points and color codes each point based on the cluster it was assigned to.  So I know all the info is somewhere in 'myBIC', but the docs and help don't seem to provide any insight as to how to print out this data!

I want to print out a new file based on the results I believe are encoded in myBIC.  Something like,

```
CLUST x, y, z
1 1.2, 3.4, 5.2
1 1.2, 3.3, 5.2
2 5.5, 1.3, 1.3
3 7.1, 1.2, -1.0
3 7.2, 1.2, -1.1
```

and then - hopefully - also print out the parameters/centroids of the individual gaussians/clusters that the clustering process found.

Surely this is an absurdly easy thing to do and I'm just too ignorant of R to figure it out...

EDIT:  I seem to have gotten a little bit further along.  Doing the following prints out a somewhat cryptic matrix,

```
    > mySummary$classification
[1] 1 1 2 1 3
[6] 1 1 1 3 1
[12] 1 2 1 3 1
[18] 1 3
```

which upon reflection I realized is actually the list of samples and their classifications. I guess it is not possible to write this directly via the write command, but a bit more experimentation in the R console lead me to realize that I can do this:

```
> newData <- mySummary$classification
> write( newData, file="class.csv" )
```

and that the result actually looks pretty nice!

```
 $ head class.csv
"","x"
"1",1
"2",2
"3",2
```

where the first column apparenly matches the index for the input data, and the second column describes the assigned class identity.

The 'mySummary$parameters' object appears to be nested though, and has a bunch of sub-objects corresponding to the individual gaussians and their parameters, etc.  The 'write' function fails when I try to just write it out, but individually writing out each sub object name is a bit tedious.  Which leads me to a new question: how do I iterate over a nested object in R and print the elements out in a serial fashion to a file descriptor?

I have this 'mySummary$parameters' object.  It is composed of several sub-objects like 'mySummary$parameters$variance$sigma', etc.  I would like to just iterate over everything and print it all to file in the same way that this is done to the CLI automatically...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To calculate the actual clustering parameters themselves (mean, variance, what cluster each point belongs to), you need to use `Mclust`.
To do the writing you can use (for example) `write.csv`.

By default `Mclust` calculates the parameters based on the most optimal model as determined by BIC, so if that's what you want to do, you can do:

```
myMclust <- Mclust(myData)
```

Then `myMclust$BIC` will contain the results for all the other models (ie `myMclust$BIC` is more-or-less the same as `mclustBIC(myData)`).

See `?Mclust` in the `Value:` section to see what other information `myMclust` has. For example, `myMclust$parameters$mean` is the mean for each cluster, `myMclust$parameters$variance` the variance for each cluster, ...

However `myMclust$classification` will contain which cluster each point belongs to, calculated for the most optimal model.

So, to get the output you want, you can do:

```
# create some data for example purposes -- you have your read.csv(...) instead.
myData <- data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100),z=runif(100))
# get parameters for most optimal model
myMclust <- Mclust(myData)
# if you wanted to do your summary like before:
mySummary <- summary( myMclust$BIC, data=myData )

# add a column in myData CLUST with the cluster.
myData$CLUST <- myMclust$classification
# now to write it out:
write.csv(myData[,c("CLUST","x","y","z")], # reorder columns to put CLUST first
          file="out.csv",                  # output filename
          row.names=FALSE,                 # don't save the row numbers
          quote=FALSE)                     # don't surround column names in ""
```

A note on the `write.csv` - if you don't put in `row.names=FALSE` you'll get an extra column in your csv containing the row number. Also, `quote=FALSE` puts your column headings as `CLUST,x,y,z` whereas otherwise they'd be `"CLUST","x","y","z"`. It's your choice.

Suppose we wanted to do the same, but use the parameters from a different model that was not optimal. However, `Mclust` calculates parameters only for the optimal model by default. To calculate parameters for a particular model (say `"EEI"`), you'd do:

```
myMclust <- Mclust(myData,modelNames="EEI")
```

and then proceed as before.

Comment: Awesome! thank you very much for the detailed rundown.  I guess it will just take a while to get used to the quirks of R (as with any new language).  This gave me some important insights into what is going on.  I'm also pretty amazed at how much I've managed to do without knowing *anything* about R.  Thanks again.

Comment: I fell into R much like you did so I know what you mean, I felt like a monkey bashing away at my keyboard when I first started :P Good luck!

Comment: I know comments are supposed to avoid "+1" & "thanks", but `myData$CLUST <- myMclust$classification` & `myMclust <- Mclust(myData,modelNames="EEI")` are beautiful, exactly what I needed. I also appended the z-scores (`MyData$PROB <- MyClust$z`) to look @ the relative probabilities for each of the records' cluster membership.

Comment: @NiuBiBang , just be aware that `MyClust$z` returns a probability matrix that shows the probability of each observation to fall in each and every cluster. So when you do `MyData$PROB <- MyClust$z` you're only getting the probabilities for the observations to fall within the first! cluster. Apart from that, thanks for the question ! If you want to get the highest probability to the cluster assingned, you should do ` MyData$PROB <-
 apply(d_clust$z, 1 , max)`